# SSH, Kerberos, AD: how / where to config /etc/pam.d/password-auth?

Tags: ssh, active-directory, centos, kerberos, pam

I have a CentOS 6 machine here and want to give SSH access for users from another forest, which is trusted. I got a temporary workaround, which is:

1. change content in `/etc/pam.d/vncserver` to:

   ```
   auth include password-auth
   ```
2. add these two lines `/etc/pam.d/password-auth`:

   ```
   auth        sufficient    pam_krb5.so use_first_pass realm=NEW.DOMAIN.NET
   password    sufficient    pam_krb5.so use_authtok realm=NEW.DOMAIN.NET
   ```

   so it looks like this:

   ```
   #%PAM-1.0
   # This file is auto-generated.
   # User changes will be destroyed the next time authconfig is run.
   auth        required      pam_env.so
   auth        sufficient    pam_unix.so nullok try_first_pass
   auth        requisite     pam_succeed_if.so uid >= 500 quiet
   auth        sufficient    pam_krb5.so use_first_pass
   auth        sufficient    pam_krb5.so use_first_pass realm=NEW.DOMAIN.NET
   auth        required      pam_deny.so

   account     required      pam_unix.so broken_shadow
   account     sufficient    pam_localuser.so
   account     sufficient    pam_succeed_if.so uid < 500 quiet
   account     [default=bad success=ok user_unknown=ignore] pam_krb5.so
   account     required      pam_permit.so

   password    requisite     pam_cracklib.so try_first_pass retry=3 type=
   password    sufficient    pam_unix.so sha512 shadow nis nullok try_first_pass use_authtok
   password    sufficient    pam_krb5.so use_authtok
   password    sufficient    pam_krb5.so use_authtok realm=NEW.DOMAIN.NET
   password    required      pam_deny.so

   session     optional      pam_keyinit.so revoke
   session     required      pam_limits.so
   session     [success=1 default=ignore] pam_succeed_if.so service in crond quiet use_uid
   session     required      pam_unix.so
   session     optional      pam_krb5.so
   ```
3. add new domain name to `/etc/krb5.conf`
4. restart SSH daemon

--> Works fine for a moment. BUT: after each `system-config-authentication` (`authconfig -update_all`) the changes from #2 are overwritten (undone) and the SSH-connection is refused then.

My question is:

- Where do I add the additional new domain to keep it working PERMANENTLY?

  - A simple substitution won't work, as the old domain / forest is still in use too.
  - Just adding the new domain just to `/etc/krb5.so` won't do the trick, as then it only checks the default domain, which is not `NEW.DOMAIN.NET`.

Comment: Nice question, but it is offtopic here. You should move it to [ServerFault](http://serverfault.com/about).